# How do I inspect from a user's view how a given page element was created by Drupal?

Tags: entities

I would like to be able to access a Drupal site as a given user/user-type (maybe using [Masquerade](http://drupal.org/project/masquerade)) and from their view of the site be able to inspect how/where the page's configs/scripts/modules/nodes/etc were loaded from.

**Background:** It's possible in the next week I'll need to take over 10+ existing Drupal sites and most likely the maintenance for the sites will be driven by request like "On this page, I'd like to change this." While it's likely that I'll just have to use what I know of Drupal and hunt down where/how the given page elements are being created/managed, it would be nice to have the option to inspect how/where a given page element is being set within Drupal given a URL and the user that accessed it; think [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Drupal.

If possible. it would be nice if this worked for 6 and 7, since the sites I believe are in 6, but will likely be ported to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Think Firebug for Drupal?

Try the [Drupal for Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) module and associated Chrome/Firefox extension :)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that comes close in my mind is [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). But I don't think you're supposed to install this on a live website, only on dev servers.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to second the vote for Firebug, (or better yet, Chrome's Inspect).

You will find. I'm sure with a certain amount of frustration, that the source of a page can come from a multitude of sources. Firebug or Chrome inspect will take you a long way in dropping hints as to how it was constructed. Then, just start looking for the code that did the deed.

As an aside, I don't think you'll get much milage from Devel for this particular problem.